# How to resolve missing column to generate html dashboard report?

Tags: jmeter

```
An error occurred: Error while processing samples:Consumer failed with message :
Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with
 message :No column <grpThreads> found in sample metadata <timeStamp,elapsed,lab
el,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes
,sentBytes,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect>, check #jmeter.save.saveservice.* prope
rties to add the missing column
```

The below are my Jmeter.Properties and User.Properties. Did I miss anything? Do I need to add anything in saveservice.properties?

**Jmeter.Properties:**

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes = true
# Only available with HttpClient4
jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.elapsed = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.dataType = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.idleTime = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.connect = true
# the timestamp format must include the time and should include the date.
# For example the default, which is milliseconds since the epoch: 
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = ms
# Or the following would also be suitable
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
```

**User.Properties:**

```
# Configure this property to change the report title
#jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=Apache JMeter Dashboard

# Change this parameter if you want to change the granularity of over time graphs.
# Granularity must be higher than 1000 (1second) otherwise Throughput graphs will be incorrect
# see Bug 60149
#jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=60000

# Change this parameter if you want to change the granularity of Response time distribution
# Set to 100 ms by default
#jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimeDistribution.property.set_granularity=100

# Change this parameter if you want to override the APDEX satisfaction threshold.
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold=1500

# Change this parameter if you want to override the APDEX tolerance threshold.
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold=3000

# Sets the destination directory for generated html pages, it is better to change it for every generation
# This will override the value set through -o command line option
# jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.output_dir=/tmp/test-report

# Indicates which graph series are filtered (regular expression)
# In the below example we filter on Search and Order samples
# Note that the end of the pattern should always include (-success|-failure)?$
# Transactions per second suffixes Transactions with "-success" or "-failure" depending 
# on the result
#jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Search|Order)(-success|-failure)?$

# Indicates whether series filter apply only on sample series
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.filters_only_sample_series=true
```

Comment: Please try generating report from existing csv. jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>..if everything goes fine then may be it is the path of input file that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue when running with an older jmeter.properties file and then generating the dashboard report with a newer version. The easiest way to fix this without editing any of properties file, is to ensure when running your test that you use the new version of jmeter.properties. If this isn't an option i.e. you don't want or are unable to rerun your tests, then you could try passing the older jmeter.properties as a parameter.

```
jmeter -g myresults.jtl -o output_results -p jmeter.properties
```

Comment: hi i had the same issue... how would i know that i can run the new version of jmeter.properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a very similar issue and fixed by cleaning up my working folder. What happened in my case: once the jmeter.properties was modified to generate the report, the generated  JTL file changed format. At least one column was added (timestamp). The problem is that jmeter was adding record to the csv file, no overriding the file. The JTL file had various records with different fields which resulted in the error above.

Comment: how did you fixed it ?