# error while trying to generate HTML report in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Getting below error while trying to generate HRML report.pls help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the report from the GUI.

Open Jmeter and select Tools > Generate HTML report

[image: Generate HTML report Menu option]

Fill in the details as required...

[image: Generate HTML report dialog]

Ensure that you select a directory that has enough space available for the report to be generated.

---

There are also a couple of options you could try on this thread;
[How to resolve missing column to generate html dashboard report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636781/how-to-resolve-missing-column-to-generate-html-dashboard-report)

Comment: But i need to try for more users thats y i run using non gui. Anyway i will try this

Comment: I don't understand... The generate html report option uses the jtl/csv results file for all users logged during the test run. It essentially replicates the command line option but just allows you to browse with buttons instead. Could you send and example of the first couple of lines in you results csv?

Comment: i need to run the script for more than 300 users.so when i run from gui it will throw memory error na? so i am running from non gui

Comment: Running a test would utilise resources but generating the HTML (after the test has finished) can be done from your local machine, it just formats the JTL file (assuming you created one during the test run - using simple data writer for example). 

You can run the HTML generation from non-gui so that it automatically completes the task after the test has been completed ... but there is no "requirement" for this action to be run in non-gui mode as it is a stand-alone task.